# Jsoup parse html for subscript and superscript

Tags: java, html, jsoup, subscript, superscript

I'm using `Jsoup`to parse clipboard value to html code but it not working for `subscript` and `superscript`. For an example:

**Superscript**
**Hello <sup>World</sup>** (HTML: `<b>Hello <sup>World</sup></b>`)

**Subscript**
**Hello <sub>World</sub>** (HTML: `<b>Hello <sub>World</sub></b>`)

**Code**

```
result = rtfToHtml(new StringReader(streamToString((InputStream) contents.getTransferData(dfRTF))));
```

The Resul for above example is:

```
< html >
  < head >
    < style >
      < !--
        p.default {
          size:3;
          family:sansserif;
          foreground:#000000;
          bold:normal;
          italic:;
        }
      -- >
    < /style >
  < /head >
  < body >
    < p class=default >
      < span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14pt; font-family: ArialMT">
        < b>Hello < /b>
      < /span>
      < span style="color: #000000; font-size: 11pt; font-family: ArialMT">
        < b>World< /b>
      < /span>
    < /p>
  < /body>
< /html>
```

Any idea how I can handle `Superscript` and `Subscript` using Jsoup. Any advice or references is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
        DataFlavor dfRTF = new DataFlavor("text/rtf", "Rich Formatted Text");
        DataFlavor dfTxt = DataFlavor.stringFlavor;

        boolean hasTransferableRTFText = (contents != null)
                && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(dfRTF);
        boolean hasTransferableTxtText = (contents != null)
                && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(dfTxt);
if (hasTransferableRTFText) {
            try {
result = rtfToHtml(new StringReader(streamToString((InputStream) contents.getTransferData(dfRTF))));
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(result);
}
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public static String rtfToHtml(Reader rtf) throws IOException { // From http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/136483/Java-How-to-convert-RTF-into-HTML
        JEditorPane p = new JEditorPane();
        p.setContentType("text/rtf");
        EditorKit kitRtf = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/rtf");
        try {
            kitRtf.read(rtf, p.getDocument(), 0);
            kitRtf = null;
            EditorKit kitHtml = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/html");
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            kitHtml.write(writer, p.getDocument(), 0, p.getDocument().getLength());
            return writer.toString();
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The current question do not contain enough detail.
What is `rtfToHtml`? Jsoup convert all as expect, but your problem is in rtfToHtml function. Is it [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/136483/Java-How-to-convert-RTF-into-HTML)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not related to JSoup, but to your rtfToHtml function.

Your function does not generates the <sub> and <sup> tags you expect.
JSoup cannot do anything a this step, because the expected tags are not here, so you cannot parse them.

**EDIT: (and Solution)**

You should skip your rtfToHTML step when not necessary. If clipboard contains the data already in HTML format, so asking for it in rtf then converting it back to HTML implies losses of format information during conversions.

You can get clipboard directly in HTML format to avoid unnecessary conversions:

```
DataFlavor dfHTML = new DataFlavor("text/html; charset=Unicode");
boolean hasTransferableHTMLText = (contents != null) && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(dfHTML);
if (hasTransferableHTMLText)
{
    InputStream is = (InputStream)contents.getTransferData(dfHTML);
    String htmldata = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is, "Unicode");  

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmldata);
    System.out.println(doc.html());
    //...
}
```

Tested with copy-to-clipboard from Chrome and FF. Both keeps the <sub> and <sup> tags you expect.

**EDIT2:**

IOUtils refers to org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

Comment: This comment still is not answered. Where does this rtfToHtml function come from? There are simply no `sup` and `sub` tags. This is not a JSoup problem but simply a problem with that method (or the source data that doesn't contain what you expect). That method seems to generate subscript as `style` with smaller text size. No chance to parse this semantically, only heuristically.

Comment: `String htmldata = IOUtils.toString(is, "Unicode");` throws error `method toString in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: InputStream,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Comment: IOUtils refers to apache commons.io library. Maybe you already have an IOUtils object in your class for another purpose. To avoid conflict, name IOUtils explicitly: `String htmldata = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is, "Unicode");`

Answer (score -1):

Use selector of Jsoup to get desired value.[This](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) link will help you.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.Connect("some url);
Elements sub= doc.select("sub");
```

Comment: There is no `sub` element in the parsed html. So `Elements sub = doc.select("sub");` will be null.